# JRuby unexpected :

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, syntax-error

I am running JRuby version 1.6.7 with Rails 3.2.3 and when I launch my rails server `rails s` I get the following error:

```
/config/routes.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':'

  match '/about', to: 'pages#about'
```

However, if I change to `match '/about' :to => 'pages#about'` I don't get the error. Since this shorthand format is supported in the version of Rails in use, what is the problem and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash syntax comes from Ruby implementations, not Rails. JRuby can run in either 1.9 or 1.8 mode. It runs in 1.8 mode by default. You can read about [configuring JRuby to run in 1.9 mode on the wiki](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/ConfiguringJRuby).

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I thought it was the Rails version. I'll call myself a fool immediately!

Answer (score 0):

The `key: value` syntax was introduced by Ruby 1.9 to supersede 1.8's `:key => value` syntax. The version of Rails is irrelevant; unless your version of *Ruby* is at least 1.9, you cannot use the new `key: value` syntax for hashes.